# basic collaborative meteorjs form fiield

Tags: meteor, collaboration

I am creating a Form inside my MeteorJS application which contains a TextArea. I am trying to make that TextArea collaboratively editable among several logged in users.  For that I am listening for Key-Up events on the textarea and capturing the position of the cursor within the TextArea, sending the diff text, position, utcTime to a server Method which inserts the text in to the Mongo record using a Find then Update.

This means that the database is being updated rapidly and frequently during a document editing session.

Is this the best way to implement such a tool?  Or should I be looking in to LiveDB - or offloading the collaborative editing to something like firePad/fireBase - and only persisting the state of the document at 30 second intervals (with a flag "saved" on the UI).